# Spring Model and View Returning blank output when returning HTML form

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am returning modelAndView object from my Spring API. And view is a JSP form.
The request param to the API is binded with DTO PaymentInput.
The API is working fine on localhost but it is giving blank response when deployed to server. I have checked the logs but there is no exception as such.

**Edited**

When I change **new ModelAndView("payuForm", "paymentInput", paymentInput);**
to ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(new MappingJackson2JsonView());
it starts returning output as Json

```
 "paymentInput": {
    "furl": "https://dev.travelkhana.com/callback/PayUfurl",
    "surl": "https://dev.travelkhana.com/callback/PayUsurl",
    "txnid": "472663",
    "key": "gtKFFx",
    "hash": "3c0eeb0cefd5c0637e0a50adee3fd0fe81af6c69f46a52b2fa50711eafa054b43af13957c02ef3a71c0dbcb8c05129829281fd256a55c0c0c04bbc40c84fd474",
    "orderid": "472663",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "emailid": "test@test.com",
    "amount": "270",
    "productinfo": "vegthali,nonvegthali",
    "firstname": "rahul",
    "phone": "9716221914"
  }
```

but still it is not working for HTML response.

payuForm.jsp

```
<%@page import="com.tk.utilities.CommonFunction"%>
 <%
 String paymentUrl = CommonFunction.getProperties("payu_payment_url");
 System.out.println("paymentUrl:"+paymentUrl);
 %>

 <html>
 <head>
 <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form:form action="<%=paymentUrl%>" method="post" id='payuForm'   modelAttribute="paymentInput">
    <form:input type="hidden" name="firstname" path="FIRSTNAME"/>
    <form:input type="hidden" name="surl"  path="surl"/>
    <form:input type="hidden" name="furl" path="furl" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="phone" path="PHONE" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="email" path="EMAIL" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="amount" path="AMOUNT" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="key" path="key" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="hash" path="hash" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="txnid" path="txnid" />

    <form:input type="hidden" name="productinfo" path="PRODUCTINFO" />

    <input type="hidden" name="isMobileView" value="1" /> 

</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Model class

```
package com.tk.payu.dto;

public class PaymentInput {

private String AMOUNT;
private String ORDERID;
private String PRODUCTINFO;
private String FIRSTNAME;
private String EMAIL;
private String EMAILID;//for mapping EMAILID to EMAIL
private String PHONE;
private String furl;
private String surl;
private String txnid;
private String key;
private String hash;

PaymentInput.java
    public String getFurl() {
        return furl;
    }
    public void setFurl(String furl) {
        this.furl = furl;
    }
    public String getSurl() {
        return surl;
    }
    public void setSurl(String surl) {
        this.surl = surl;
    }
    public String getTxnid() {
        return txnid;
    }
    public void setTxnid(String txnid) {
        this.txnid = txnid;
    }
    public String getAMOUNT() {
        return AMOUNT;
    }
    public void setAMOUNT(String aMOUNT) {
        AMOUNT = aMOUNT;
    }
    public String getORDERID() {
        return ORDERID;
    }
    public void setORDERID(String oRDERID) {
        ORDERID = oRDERID;
    }

    public String getPRODUCTINFO() {
        return PRODUCTINFO;
    }
    public void setPRODUCTINFO(String pRODUCTINFO) {
        PRODUCTINFO = pRODUCTINFO;
    }
    public String getFIRSTNAME() {
        return FIRSTNAME;
    }
    public void setFIRSTNAME(String fIRSTNAME) {
        FIRSTNAME = fIRSTNAME;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getHash() {
        return hash;
    }
    public void setHash(String hash) {
        this.hash = hash;
    }
    public String getPHONE() {
        return PHONE;
    }
    public void setPHONE(String pHONE) {
        PHONE = pHONE;
    }
    public String getEMAIL() {
        return EMAIL;
    }
    public void setEMAIL(String eMAIL) {
        EMAIL = eMAIL;
    }
    public String getEMAILID() {
        return EMAILID;
    }
    public void setEMAILID(String eMAILID) {
        EMAILID = eMAILID;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payuPaymentNew", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView payuPaymentNew(
            @ModelAttribute("paymentInput") PaymentInput paymentInput,
            BindingResult result) throws IOException {

        String SURL = CommonFunction.getProperties("payu_surl");
        String FURL = CommonFunction.getProperties("payu_furl");
        System.out.println("order id:" + paymentInput.getORDERID());
        String salt = CommonFunction.getProperties("salt");
        String key = CommonFunction.getProperties("key");

        paymentInput.setSurl(SURL);
        paymentInput.setFurl(FURL);
        paymentInput.setKey(key);



        System.out.println("payumasterDao:.....");
        return new ModelAndView("payuForm", "paymentInput", paymentInput);


    }
```

Expected Output

```
<html>
    <head>

</head>
    <body>
        <form id="payuForm" action="" method="post">
            <input id="FIRSTNAME" name="FIRSTNAME" name="firstname" type="hidden" value="rahul"/>
            <input id="surl" name="surl" name="surl" type="hidden" value=""/>
            <input id="furl" name="furl" name="furl" type="hidden" value="/>
            <input id="PHONE" name="PHONE" name="phone" type="hidden" value="9716221914"/>
            <input id="EMAIL" name="EMAIL" name="email" type="hidden" value="test@test.com"/>
            <input id="AMOUNT" name="AMOUNT" name="amount" type="hidden" value="270"/>
            <input id="key" name="key" name="key" type="hidden" value=""/>
            <input id="hash" name="hash" name="hash" type="hidden" value="3c0eeb0cefd5c0637e0a50adee3f/>
            <input id="txnid" name="txnid" name="txnid" type="hidden" value="472663"/>
            <input id="PRODUCTINFO" name="PRODUCTINFO" name="productinfo" type="hidden" value="vegthali,nonvegthali"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="isMobileView" value="1" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

XML entry

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

Comment: Remove `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I tried removing @ResponseBody but it does't work for me.Actually the API /payuPaymentNew is working as expected on localhost but same code returns blank response on server.

Comment: `@ResponseBody` is for return the result as it and not to be interpreted, so it cannot have worked (unless you use a completely different configuration on both systems). Also i you use `@RestController` you should remove that and use `@Controller` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@ResponseBody` from your controller.

`@ResponseBody` annotation is basically telling Spring: take the object I (method) return and use any serializer you have that supports it and write it directly to the body of the HTTP response. **There's no JSP involved here**.

Comment: I tried removing @ResponseBody but it does't work for me.Actually the API **/payuPaymentNew** is working as expected on localhost but same code returns blank response on server.

Comment: Can you test change:  return new ModelAndView("payuForm", "paymentInput", paymentInput); for

Comment: Can you test change:  `return new ModelAndView("payuForm", "paymentInput", paymentInput);` for  `return new ModelAndView("**P**ayuForm", "paymentInput", paymentInput);`

Comment: The name name of my jsp file is payuForm.jsp not PayuForm.jsp I have edited it in question also.

Comment: I tried changing output to json view using **ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(new MappingJackson2JsonView());**  now its returning

Comment: "paymentInput": {
    "txnid": "472663",
    "key": "gtKFFx",
    "hash": "3c0eeb0cefd5c0637e0a50adee3fd0fe81af6c69f46a52b2fa50711eafa054b43af13957c02ef3a71c0dbcb8c05129829281fd256a55c0c0c04bbc40c84fd474",
    "orderid": "472663",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "emailid": "test@test.com",
    "amount": "270",
    "productinfo": "vegthali,nonvegthali",
    "firstname": "rahul",
    "phone": "9716221914"
  }